remapping external bluetooth keyboard on android
I'm using an external Bluetooth keyboard on my Samsung galaxy tab s8, so at the keyboard there is no cmd/windows button on the layout, that cmd button work as windows button on windows computer keyboard. currently I'm using a key mapper from google playstore to mapping the button of the Bluetooth keyboard, but I dont know the key code of that cmd or windows button, is there some other way for me obtaining that windows button or anyone know the tips, my device have not rooted yet, please help me, thank you.
I tried key mapping from google playstore, I don't know the cmd or windows keycode to be mapping for my Bluetooth keyboard.
